# Detect if application running in remote app

Tags: c#-4.0, rdp

Is there a way to detect from an application written in c# if it's being launched as a remote app using RDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the parent of your application's process and check if it's raised by rdpinit.exe. If so, it's a RemoteApp.

Quick example for getting the parent-process-id (sorry, vb.net):

```
<Extension()>
    Public Function GetParentProcessId(process As Process) As Integer
        If process Is Nothing Then Throw New NullReferenceException()

        Dim parentProcessId As Integer
        Dim snapShot As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

        Try
            snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(SnapshotFlags.Process, 0)

            If snapShot <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Dim procEntry As New PROCESSENTRY32
                procEntry.dwSize = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(PROCESSENTRY32)))

                If Process32First(snapShot, procEntry) Then
                    Do
                        If process.Id = procEntry.th32ProcessID Then
                            parentProcessId = CInt(procEntry.th32ParentProcessID)
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop While Process32Next(snapShot, procEntry)
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            If snapShot <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                CloseHandle(snapShot)
            End If
        End Try

        Return parentProcessId
    End Function
```

Now you can get the parent-process easily.

Regards,
Jan